# how find by simple iteration 5 decimal this function

Tags: calculus, number-theory

how find by simple iteration 5 decimal this function

[image]

I assumed that y1= sin(x) , and y2=5x-2
[image]
to draw them and get the intersection to get the initial x

thus, I got  x0= 0.5

what next how to get the other x values

please explain me the way

someone told me that the x values will be

x1 = 0.5000000000

x2 = 0.4950091272

x3 = 0.4950076823

x4 = 0.4950076821

x5 = 0.4950076823

but I don't know how he got these values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We re-write it as:

$$x = \dfrac{\sin x + 2}{5}$$

This gives us the iteration formula:

$$x_{n+1} = \dfrac{\sin x_n + 2}{5}$$

Use [*Fixed Point Iteration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) with $x_0 = \dfrac 12$, we get $x_1 = 0.495885107721$ and it generates iterates that converge to:

$$x_{12} = 0.495007682286$$

I will let you give the other iterations a go.

Note, for comparison purposes, you can also use [*Newton's Method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) with the iteration formula:

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x)}{f'(x)} = x_n - \dfrac{\sin(x_n)-5x_n+2}{\cos(x_n)-5}$$

With $x_0 = \dfrac 12$, it converges in three (12-digit precision) steps with:

$$x_3 = 0.495007682286$$

Comment: but when I substituted with x0=1/2 in the x_(n+1) to get x1 , it give me 0.40175 not 0.495885107721

Comment: Is your calculator using radians or degrees (should be radians)? Actually, I think your calculator is using gradians, change it to radians.

Comment: yes, it was degrees , I set it to R and now is working good many thanks

Comment: I accepted it  and also up-vote